# What do different symbols mean in google-colab auto autocomplete?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Google-Colab has auto autocomplete, but what do the little symbols mean at the left, and how many different symbols are there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For clarity, here is an example of the little symbols:

[image: Example of completion icons]

The icons distinguish the type of the completion, e.g., functions, modules, properties, and so on. Here's a decoder ring:

[image: Icons to completion type]